# What's wrong with my lua?

Tags: lua

My first foray into lua, and this just doesn't work. It says that I'm trying to call global exiter (a nil value). I'm just doing a simple program to try and get functions to work.

```
print("hello world")
io.read()
y = 0

while y < 10 do
    local x = ""
    print("hello world")
    x = io.read()
    if x == "y" then
    y = exiter(1)
    print(y)
    end
end

function exiter(param)
    local q = 0
    print ("hello again")
    q = param * 10
    return q;
end
```

Comment: This is certainly still reproducible and not a simple typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lua programs are executed top-to-bottom, statement-by-statement. So, when you enter `while` loop, the function `exiter` has not come into existence yet. Define it before going into the loop:

```
function exiter(param)
    local q = 0
    print ("hello again")
    q = param * 10
    return q;
end

while y < 10 do
    local x = ""
    print("hello world")
    x = io.read()
    if x == "y" then
        y = exiter(1)
        print(y)
    end
end
```

Comment: To be clear, functions don't have such identities. `exiter` is simply a variable that, at some points (end of line 6 to line 16), references a function value created from execution of the function definition (line 1 to line 6).

Answer (score 3):

Function definitions occur when the code for them is run. You aren't creating the `exiter` function until **after** you try to call it in the while loop. Reverse the order of your loop and function definition.

Answer (score 3):

```
function exiter(param)
    -- ...
end
```

Is simple syntactic sugar for creating a closure and assigning it to `exite`, which is

- either a local variable defined earlier in the same or a containing scope,
- or a global variable (aka element of the environment-table `__ENV`:

```
exiter = function(param)
    -- ...
end
```

Before you execute the assignment, that variable has its previous value, `nil` if not yet assigned.

Similar for `local function`:

```
local function exiter(param)
    -- ...
end
```

is equivalent to *first* defining a local variable and *then* doing the same as without `local`:

```
local exiter
exiter = function(param)
    -- ...
end
```

That means any use of `exiter` before that function statement would not refer to the new local. Defining the local before the assignment is neccessary in order to allow recursive calls, this is not equivalent and does not work:

```
local exiter = function(param)
    -- ... cannot recursively call exiter here
end
```